# How to embed angular app content in another on-angular web app

Tags: angular, jboss7.x

My legacy web application is running on Jboss 7.x server/HTML5/Struts type MVC framework. This legacy web application has a content view which is implemented as an IFrame control in the HTML page. We dynamically set the "src" property of IFrame, to load different content.

In the process of migrating our legacy application to Angular5, we want to take step by step approach and first implement content view using Angular. So we plan to host content view in a separate angular app, and embed this content in legacy app page.

**Legacy application runtime details:**
    mycompany.com:8082/legacyApp

**Angualar5 web app runtime details:**
    mycompany.com:4100/configview/dynamic_url_part

Below is my attempt to set Angular content in legacy web application page:

```html
<iframe id='navFrame' name='navFrame' src='http://mycompany.com:4100/configview/dynamic_url_part'></iframe>
```

When I startup my legacy JBoss app and try click a link that sets the "src" property and refresh the whole page, I get 404 error message inside the IFrame window. i.e. The Angular content is not found/not loading. Rest of legacy page loads fine.

I understand there is CORS issue that I need to fix, since I'm accessing a different port. Although I went through some CORS documentation and posts it it is not clear to me what what I should change and in which app? Legacy and/or angular5.

Any clear steps to take is appreciated, since I can change/configure both apps.

Comment: I don't think that CORS would give you 404 error. Does http://mycompany.com:4100/configview/dynamic_url_part direct url work?

Comment: Yes, the direct URL works.

Comment: I'm not sure what happened. I cleared cache on browser,restarted servers and the error is NOT 404 anymore. The error is ** SCRIPT5022: Exception thrown and not caught **.

Comment: Also the error is on IE10. I do not get error in Chrome, Firefox.  How to fix this issue in IE 10 since legacy app is supported on IE 10.

Comment: I see that SCRIPT5022 is security issue, I guess due to iframe. I don't do JBoss, so I'm not sure if I can suggest anything here. But this problem could possibly be recreated with static web servers. Consider providing http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and a way to replicate it - a repo, etc. I'm not sure if it can be replicated with Plunker because of CORS, but if it can, it would be useful here.